# Phonegap Version not supported in the blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, build, phonegap-build

From the last 15days i am working in the phonegap . I did one application. When i zip and upload build.phonegap.com the ios,android and windows build was succes. But the Blackberry is not possible I have got one error.

```
phonegap version not supported blackberry
```

For that i have goggled and changed so many ways but i didn't succeed can please help me one that.

config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.us-dr" version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Triangle</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.5.0" />    
</widget>
```

Comment: which version of blackberry are you trying to build for? have you tried downgrading phonegap version to 3.4.0?

Comment: you can have a look over here.[phonegap blackberry support](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/blackberry_symbian_and_webos_will_not_be_supported_by_phonegap_3_0)